# Case sensitiveness of kubectl command flag values

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm new to the kubernetes. This question is related to the `--restart` flag value used with the kubectl command.

When I run below command I'm getting an error saying `error: invalid restart policy: never`.
Command: `kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=never`.

But when I run the below command I could create a pod without any issue.
Command: `kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never`.
Can we consider the values related to the flags in kubectl are case sensitive.  Can someone explain this ? Thanks in advance :)

Case sensitiveness related to the kubectl command related flag values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs ([1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands)) the allowed values are:

```
supported values: OnFailure, Never
```

If a command is case insensitive it usually says so in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. @2240. Couldn't find the mentioning of a case sensitiveness in there.